# What processes can survive logging out of Linux, and what not?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, signals, logout

I am trying to understand what happens when we log out of Linux (Ubuntu specifically):

- How does a process initially request/notify the logging out process to perform logging out (by sending some signals, or some other IPC means)? What is the program run by the logging out process? What is usually the program run by the requesting/notifying process?
- What processes will the logging out process kill and what not? (There are ways to make processes started after logging in survive logging out, and how do they manage to do that? Making a process not having a controlling terminal seems to be a way, but most of the processes killed by logging out in the following examples don't have a controlling terminal)
- How does the logging out process kill those processes (by sending some signals, or some other IPC means)?

Consider three cases: virtual console and desktop environment and SSH. (The first two are provided by the OS, and the third isn't, though all are running in user space)

1. When I log in virtual console, I get the following
   ancestry processes from the login shell:

   ```
   1 systemd
   721 login
   26284 bash
   ```

   After I log out, processes `721 login` and below disappear.
2. On Lubuntu 18.04, when I log in lightdm and LXDE, and run lxterminal
   from the desktop's panel and get the ancestor processes from the
   following command in the lxterminal window:

   ```
   $ ps -paus $$
   systemd,1 --system --deserialize 19
     `-lightdm,661
         `-lightdm,27302 --session-child 13 24
             `-lxsession,27309,testme -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
                 `-lxpanel,27399 --profile Lubuntu
                     `-lxterminal,27565
                         `-bash,27568
                             `-pstree,27594 -paus 27568
   ```

   When I log out, the processes `lightdm,27302` and below
   disappear.
3. After I ssh into Lubuntu 18.04:

   ```
   $ pstree -a -p   -s $$
   systemd,1 --system --deserialize 19
     └─sshd,669 -D
         └─sshd,22838 
             └─sshd,22979  
                 └─bash,22980
                     └─pstree,30610 -a -p -s 22980
   ```

   After I log out, all the processes starting from `sshd,22838` to
   below disappear.

Thanks.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490267/prevent-logoff-from-killing-tmux-session

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how  systemd (especially `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind`) is involved in OS logout process.

Following is my partial answers:

1. [`The login` process `wait()` on the login shell process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887813/how-does-the-login-program-in-linux-invoke-a-login-shell), and when the login shell exits, `login` will receive `SIGCHLD` and wake up to resume its execution, which is to also exit.
2. It seems that [a logout request program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171384/674) such as `lxsession-logout`  [sends `SIGTERM` to the `lxsession` process](https://github.com/lxde/lxsession/blob/45f58c57cac27a0443d859462414352de7f33f42/lxsession-logout/lxsession-logout.c#L194)  (I said "seems" because I don't quite understand the source code).  I don't know how `lxsession` responds to `SIGTERM` and why its descendants also die, as [I can't find   its disposition](https://github.com/lxde/lxsession/blob/master/lxsession/main.vala). I don't know why the parent `lightdm,27302` of `lxsession` also die, and guess [the parent `lightdm,27302` may  `wait()` on `lxsession` and die once wake up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490321/what-does-lightdm-session-child-12-19-mean#comment899501_490414).
3. I don't know  what happens when I log out of SSH. I guess it is similar to CLI login (case 1), `sshd,22979` might wait on `bash,22980` and die. but I really don't know why there are so many `sshd` processes.

Answer (score -4):

REMEMBER, I'M NOT GONNA TELL EVERY DETAIL, BECAUSE EVEN I DO, YOU ARE NOT ABLE TO UNDERSTAND. I ALSO KNOW YOU ARE NOT FAMINLIAR WITH EVERY CONCEPT, BUT IT'S GOOD FOR YOU TO READ MANPAGES.

> How does a process initially request/notify the logging out process to perform logging out (by sending some signals, or some other IPC means)? What is the program run by the logging out process? What is usually the program run by the requesting/notifying process?

Suppose you mean "session manager" by "logging out process". By IPC with `logind`. `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-logind`. Any program that can IPC with `logind`.

> What processes will the logging out process kill and what not? (There are ways to make processes started after logging in survive logging out, and how do they manage to do that? Making a process not having a controlling terminal seems to be a way, but most of the processes killed by logging out in the following examples don't have a controlling terminal)

Processes inside this session would be killed, and if that's the last session of a user, and the user's not linger-enabled, the whole user slice is destroyed. By not killing it. Almost nothing to do with control-terminal, because `logind` doesn't use that kernel functionality.

> How does the logging out process kill those processes (by sending some signals, or some other IPC means)?

Complex logic including pre-defined action in unit files and signals.

1,2,3 Looking at process tree doesn't work. `logind` doesn't care about that. Basically, systemd-style of services and sessions manangement is cgroup. See `systemctl status`.

Comment: Thanks. Does logging out of OS refer to logging out of a `lxsession` process or a `systemd-login` session?  Is there some relation between a `lxsession` process and a `systemd-login` session?

Comment: You should answer the question, not the person. We may all greatly benefit from your deep knowledge and understanding of systemd's design and inner workings ;-) -- provided that you give some context (that not every system is running systemd), and phrase your insights in a less koan-like manner ("By IPC with login. Any program that can IPC with logind.")

Comment: I  upvoted your reply just to make  it more visible.

Comment: @Tim: That's a terrible reason to upvote a post.

Comment: The fancy blurring feature hurts my eyes. @palswim

Comment: @Tim: Not to derail the usefulness of the comments, but you can hover over the post with your mouse and it will unfade the text.

Comment: @palswim regardless, could you help with my post?